# Not able to get prompt while connectiong through Telnet command

Tags: telnet

I am trying to connect one terminal using Telnet command. It is showing connecting to  ... and after that it showing 'SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.0'. Prompt is not showing. I am able to connect through putty to this server and able to run the commands. Could you please help why is it showing this by connecting through telnet?

Answer (score 1):

[Telnet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telnet) and [SSH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Shell) are two different protocols, think of them like HTTP and HTTPS. HTTPS compatible browsers usually also work with HTTP, just like many SSH terminals (putty) also work with telnet.

If you want to connect to a SSH server, you need to use a SSH compatible client.